# Overriding len in __init__.py - python

Tags: python, monkeypatching, shadowing, built-in

I would like to assign an another function to len in `__init__.py` file of my package the following way:

```
llen = len
len = lambda x: llen(x) - 1
```

It works fine, but only in the `__init__.py` file. How can I make it affect other modules in my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to load a name that is not defined as a module-level global or a function local, Python looks it up in the `__builtin__`(`builtins` in Python 3) module. In both versions of Python, this module is also availabe as `__builtins__` in the global scope. You can modify this module and **this will affect not only your code but any python code anywhere that runs after your code runs!!**

```
import __builtin__ as builtins # import builtins in python 3
llen = len
builtins.len = lambda a:llen(a) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked fine for me :)

Comment: **`__builtins__` is a private implementation detail in CPython.** You should explicitly import the `builtins` module (or `__builtin__` in Python 2) instead.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I wouldn't do this if I were you (and I'm pretty sure you can't easily, anyway).

The reason why you shouldn't is that python uses `len` internally on it's objects to perform certain operations. 
Another reason is pure broken logic. Your `len` function defined above would return a *negative length* for empty lists, or empty things. This seems quite broken to me.

What you *can* do, is override the length method only on certain classes (this might make a lot of sense for you). For this you can use operator overloading, just override the method `__len__` in your class:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __len__(self,):
        # Do your thing
```

You may also want to look into meta classes, there is a very good [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) question on this subject.

Comment: I agree with you! I know such a behaviour is not really appropiate. But this code is a part of my university homework. I have to create a program with really annoying and hard to find bug. I thought assigning something different to an easy and often used function (such as len) is a nice idea! :)